# How to create a play a video in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a chrome extension (not for new tab) and want to auto play a muted video every time the user goes to a specific website.

I attempted to try it out in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/i-empty/pen/qBKaMRd) and it's still not playing the video.

```
// Video BG
let videoContainer = document.createElement("video");
videoContainer.id = "video";
videoContainer.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(236,55,55,.5)";
videoContainer.style.zIndex = "-1";
videoContainer.style.width = "100%";
videoContainer.style.height = "100vw";
videoContainer.style.marginTop = "50x";
videoContainer.style.position = "fixed";
videoContainer.style.top = "0";
videoContainer.src =
  "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2F6f%2F8a%2F7d%2F6f8a7d0ce651ac3ee11046c18b57d232.gif&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=8431012b0b8c3e7404333b537bb0e673adedd1bb00ff35ae9f65003423c0855c&ipo=images";
//videoContainer.type = "video/mp4";
videoContainer.muted = true;
videoContainer.autoplay = true;
videoContainer.loop = true;
videoContainer.controls = false;

document.body.append(videoContainer);
```

I'm pretty new to coding by the way. Thanks to all who can help.

Comment: The video is auto-playing in the CodePen on Firefox Nightly 108.0a1. Maybe there’s a Chrome setting that disallows auto play regardless of whether the video is muted or not. Maybe extensions disallow this by default, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

No problem if you are new, you can check in the **MDN official documentation**, we have the **[HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)** `play()` method attempts to begin playback of the media. It returns a **[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)** which is resolved when playback has been successfully started.

- You can try using this **async function** to do that! ;)

```js
const videoElem = document.querySelector("#video");
const playButton = document.querySelector("#playbutton");

playButton.addEventListener("click", handlePlayButton, false);
playVideo();

async function playVideo() {
  try {
    await videoElem.play();
    playButton.classList.add("playing");
  } catch (err) {
    playButton.classList.remove("playing");
  }
}

function handlePlayButton() {
  if (videoElem.paused) {
    playVideo();
  } else {
    videoElem.pause();
    playButton.classList.remove("playing");
  }
}
```

Comment: But awaiting `.play` is not necessary to actually _play_ the video. If `videoElem.play();` doesn’t play the video, then adding an `await` in front of it won’t make it work either.

Comment: That's true, actually what would you do it exactly? I want to know ;) @Sebastian Simon

Comment: Well, since it works for me, leave it as is. The issue is more likely in browser permissions and JS can’t circumvent these.

Comment: Great, yes I know JS can't sometimes, thanks for the support.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `await` and is proper usage for dealing with promise rejections in a try/catch block. The recommendation to call `play()` and update the UI/app in response to the resolution or rejection of the promise is an improvement over using the `autoplay` attribute and then just dropping your `video` into the DOM hoping it will work (which we know it will not in all browsers).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the source,

```
videoContainer.src = "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2F6f%2F8a%2F7d%2F6f8a7d0ce651ac3ee11046c18b57d232.gif&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=8431012b0b8c3e7404333b537bb0e673adedd1bb00ff35ae9f65003423c0855c&ipo=images";
```

was in fact not '**.mp4**' but a '**.gif**'. I tried changing the type as '***video/'asterik'***' to accept all video file types, but it failed to display the '**.gif**' file.

***My fix:*** Simply changing the video source to be an ".mp4" type. i.e "myvideo.mp4"

***Questions:***

- Is 'video/*' not the correct way to include all video formats?
- Is a '.gif' not a video file?

**Thanks to all that helped!**

Comment: A GIF is [`image/gif`](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks a lot! I had no idea it was a type image and not video.